# How to extract or modify a small piece of commited code in a far away previous commitiece code

Tags: git

I need to extract a snippet of code in `app/views/cgi_testing_seeds/index.html.haml`,
form this commit '77df270', because it should be owned by other commit.

It's very complicated to revert or rollback to that commit '77df270',
Then redo all the remaining commits again,

For example If I only want to revert the code of `index method` in the `CgiTestingSeedsController.rb`,

And add it into the commit `4b733c5` , how to ?

Or extract the code of the method and keep it in staged status, how to ?

What's an easier to do this in Git.

### Brief log

```
4b733c5 - (HEAD, feature/testing_seeds_model) Scaffold:Testing seed and generate testing data via 'faker gem' (7 minutes ago) <poc7667>
2fd8204 - (develop) Merge branch 'hotfix/wrong_column_names_in_CGIparamters' into develop (4 days ago) <poc7667>
052e2ff - Remove 'name' in 'cgi_attributes' and fix wrong name for 'default_value' (4 days ago) <poc7667>
77df270 - Scaffold: CgiTestingSeed (2 days ago) <poc7667>
```

### Changed file in the commit 77df270

```
77df270 - Scaffold: CgiTestingSeed (2 days ago) <poc7667>
app/assets/javascripts/cgi_testing_seeds.js.coffee
app/controllers/cgi_testing_seeds_controller.rb
app/helpers/cgi_testing_seeds_helper.rb
```

### CgiTestingSeedsController.rb in the commit 77df270

```
class CgiTestingSeedsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cgi_testing_seed, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /cgi_testing_seeds
  # GET /cgi_testing_seeds.json
  def index
    @cgi_testing_seeds = CgiTestingSeed.all
  end

  # GET /cgi_testing_seeds/1
  # GET /cgi_testing_seeds/1.json
  def show
  end
```

Comment: It's quite vague what you actually want to do, but you probably need cherrypicking. https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html.

Comment: @CommuSoft I updated it, I hope can make it more clear.

Comment: Why not copy & paste?

Comment: @Basilevs But I should remove the piece code from the commit, right? Because it shouldn't  occur there .

Comment: If you want to remove a portion of code, you should've said so. "Extract" is  a bad wording for that.

Comment: If you want to alter your commit history you'll have to replace everything from that change forward using  rebase/cherry-pick/filter-branch/whathaveyou.

Answer (score 1):

> For example If I only want to revert the code of `index` method in the CgiTestingSeedsController.rb,

You could consider making a patch, using git diff:

```
git diff 77df270 77df270~ > revert.diff
vi revert.diff # leave only changes regarding the `index` method
```

Note the order `77df270 77df270~`: a diff *from* what you changed (`77df270`) *to* what you had before the changes: `77df270~`: this is done to *revert* the changes in `77df270`.

> And add it into the commit 4b733c5 , how to ?

You can [apply your diff patch file](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/03/git-patch-create-and-apply/) using [`git apply`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320940/6309)):

```
git apply revert.diff
```

Since it doesn't create a commit, you can then use `git commit --amend` to modify your current latest commit.