# Git : apply the diff between two branches directly to master

Tags: git

I have a branch b1, and another b2 which builds on b1. I can see now that b2 is not dependent on b1, and I'd like to create a PR based on the diff `b2 - b1` and put that up for merging into master first.

I can see the diff on github if I set it up to compare with b1 (see image), but have no idea how to extract that as a separate PR.

[image: diff summary]

I guess I need to save the diff to a file and then create a branch from master to apply that to.

Per the request @LeGEC, this is the result

```
* ec82b57a7 (origin/sh/datatree-queries, sh/datatree-queries) tidier
* ddcb05459 tidier
* 6ebb2199f tidier
* 10e3a5e0f clipboard items
* ff08a1310 wip - UI
* 0169a4dbe insert entire query ast
| * 4e8a00c1a (HEAD -> sh/datatree-fx, origin/sh/datatree-fx) revert
|/  
o 63d147bc7 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master' into sh/datatree-fx
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git rebase` to take the commits specific to `b2` and replay them on top of master :

```
# the following command says :
#  - apply on master
#  - the list of commits starting from 'b1' ('b1' excluded)
#  - up to 'b2' ('b2' included)
git rebase --onto master b1 b2
```

then open a PR for `b2`

---

[edit]

In your case : `b1` has on extra commit, which explains the difference in behavior :

- `git rebase --onto master b1 b2` would only select the 6 commits on the left side of the graph,
- `git diff b1 b2`, on the other hand, takes also into account the differences in content with the `revert` commit

In your situation : creating the patch and applying it is a valid way to reach the result you want.

Comment: I ran `git rebase --onto master sh/datatree-fx sh/datatree-queries` (cf image added to question) but I have just 2 files and these are not the changes between the two branches. The second branch does build cleanly on top of the first so I'm confused.

Comment: You fixed your problem, and that's what matters ; if you have some extra time : can you add to your question the output of : `git log --oneline --graph --boundary sh/dataree-fx...sh/datatree-queries` (3 dots between the two branch names) ?

Answer (score 1):

I have since found [How do you take a git diff file, and apply it to a local branch that is a copy of the same repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320863/how-do-you-take-a-git-diff-file-and-apply-it-to-a-local-branch-that-is-a-copy-o)

What worked was to cd to the root of the repo and then

```
git diff sh/datatree-fx sh/datatree-queries > mydiff.diff
git apply mydiff.diff
```