# Apply diff, using a given strategy

Tags: git, patch

#### Question

I have:

- A Git Repository
- A Patch (`.diff`) with several conflicts

I would like to apply the patch using a strategy (like `theirs`), similar to [`git merge -s`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt--sltstrategygt). Can this be achieved using `git` and/or `patch`?

### EDIT

The original question wasn't very clear of what I'm trying to do. **I have many merge conflicts from `patch --merge`, and I'd like to resolve them the same way**
(similar to [`git merge --strategy ...`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt--sltstrategygt))

#### Related

- [Resolve Git merge conflicts in favor of their changes during a pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697463/resolve-git-merge-conflicts-in-favor-of-their-changes-during-a-pull)
- [How do you take a git diff file, and apply it to a local branch that is a copy of the same repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320863/how-do-you-take-a-git-diff-file-and-apply-it-to-a-local-branch-that-is-a-copy-o)

Comment: How did you produce the diff file?

Comment: note that there is a difference between an actual merge (where git has the complete content of 3 versions : "base", "ours" and "theirs") and a version + a patch (which is the same as having "ours" version, the diff between "base" and "theirs", but not the content of "base" or even the diff between "base" and "ours"). Depending on how the patch applies, some cases may not fit the "use theirs" action you can do on a merge. Hence the question of eftshift0.

Comment: You need to apply the diff on the base used to create it, then you can use merge

Comment: @eftshift0 I'm patching [suckless software](https://dwm.suckless.org). The [patch](https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/single_tagset/) was downloaded from their website

Comment: @Ôrel I didn't create the diff... I'd like to apply it using the `their` strategy, but `git apply` doesn't support `--strategy`

Comment: @Ôrel can I convert a `diff` file into a git branch?

Comment: @GooseDeveloper : which patch in particular ?

Comment: It seems a bit curious that they don't just provide a repository (e.g., on GitHub).

Comment: @LeGEC https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/single_tagset/

Comment: @torek Suckless software is a bit odd... They do provide git repositories (like the [one I'm using](https://git.suckless.org/dwm/)), but the patches are provided in `diff` format, rather than as git branches

Answer (score 3):

The patches listed on that page somehow mention what commit they should be applied on :

- three of them mention they apply to version `6.2`, `6.1` or `6.0`,
- the other ones mention a commit hash in their name.

So, to apply the suggestion "create a branch and merge" (suggested by @eftshift0 or @Ôrel) :

```
git checkout -b with-patch <target commit: tag or has>
git apply <patch>
git commit
```

then switch back to your own branch, and use either `merge` or `cherry-pick` :

```
git checkout my-branch

git merge with-patch
# or
git cherry-pick with-patch
```

Comment: `git apply` fails... I'd like to resolve all merge conflicts using `--strategy theirs`, but `git apply` doesn't support it

Answer (score 2):

Find the base revision for the patch and apply it there. There should be no conflicts, right?

```
git checkout -b temp the-base-revision
git apply the-diff-file
git commit-m 'the patch' -a
```

Then feel free to cherry-pifk, which should give you access to tbe options you are looking for.

```
git checkout blahblah # where I really wamt to apply it
git cherry-pick --someOption tenp
```

That should work.

Comment: `git apply` fails, but I see what you are suggesting